# Why are there so many iOS launch screen images

Tags: trigger.io

Could someone explain why there are so many iOS launch screen images?

The launchimages module (plugin) contains 11 different sized images where as the iOS UI documentation only talks about 7.

> Create launch images in the following sizes:

For iPhone 5 and iPod touch (5th generation):

> 640 x 1136 pixels

For other iPhone and iPod touch devices:

> 640 x 960 pixels
>
> 320 x 480 pixels (standard resolution)

For iPad portrait:

> 1536 x 2048 pixels
>
> 768 x 1024 pixels (standard resolution)

For iPad landscape:

> 2048 x 1536 pixels
>
> 1024 x 768 pixels (standard resolution)

[iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/LaunchImages.html)

Trigger.io has the following:

**For iPad**

Retina, landscape iPad devices running iOS<7

> 2048x1496

Retina, landscape iPad devices running iOS7

> 2048x1536

Non-retina, landscape iPad devices running iOS<7

> 1024x748

Non-retina, landscape iPad devices running iOS7

> 1024x768

Retina, portrait iPad devices running iOS<7

> 1536x2008

Retina, portrait iPad devices running iOS7

> 1536x2048

Non-retina, portrait iPad devices running iOS<7

> 768x1004

Non-retina, portrait iPad devices running iOS7

> 768x1024

**For iPhone**

Non-retina, 3.5 inch iPhone/iPod devices

> 320x480

Retina, 4 inch iPhone/iPod devices

> 640x1136

Retina, 3.5 inch iPhone/iPod devices

> 640x960

Comment: And what sizes are included in trigger.io?

Comment: Actually, let me guess. The extras are 300x480, 460x320, 600x960, 920x640.

Comment: @Kevin added trigger.io's screen sizes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In older versions of iOS you could choose to have the status bar present or not on app launch. If it was present, you needed to take 20 pts (20px@1x, 40px@2x) off the launch images. You would only need to include one set of images, truncated or not as was appropriate for your launch options. Apparently trigger.io still recognizes the older sizes for iPad apps.

Comment: So what you are saying as they are forcing you to put in iPad sizes that might not be needed?

Comment: Do they require you to add every size? Then yes.